# Sensibly utilize ATOMIC_REQUESTS by handling some errors in the 500 handler and presenting normal HTTP responses in those cases

Tags: python, django

When `ATOMIC_REQUESTS` is enabled, each view is wrapped in a transaction. If a view raises an exception, the transaction is rolled back, which is handy. The problem is, you have to allow the exception to propagate past the view, and you would get HTTP 500 as a result.

Therefore to utilize `ATOMIC_REQUESTS`, it deems necessary to override `handler500` with our own implementation, which would check the exception causing the error and provide a normal user-friendly HTTP 200 response where appropriate, otherwise falling back to the default response, which is a stack trace in `DEBUG` mode or the default Django `handler500` otherwise.

E.g.

```
class UserFriendlyError(Exception):
    pass

def my_view(request):
    # Do some database work here...
    if request.GET['foo'] == 'bar': # Some condition
        # The idea is to show this to user. my_custom_handler500 would handle this
        raise UserFriendlyError("Don't do this, this is deprecated -- do that instead")
    # Normal exceptions can happen too and would provide a real HTTP 500 instead
    # ...

def my_custom_500(request):
    ex = sys.exc_info()[1]
    if isinstance(ex, UserFriendlyError):
        # Return a normal 200 response
        return render(request, 'user_friendly_error.html', {'exception': ex})
    # Otherwise fall back to the default handler
    return django.views.defaults.server_error(request)
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20682954/atomic-request-and-transactions-in-django-1-6]) for more background.

The problem is, when `DEBUG` mode is active, the `handler500` machinery is [circumvented with the stack trace debug handler](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#the-500-server-error-view). However, to make this work, the custom 500 handler should still be called in `DEBUG` mode, but fall back to the debug stack trace handler instead of the default 500 handler.

Is there a way to make this work, preferably without hacking Django's guts? Or perhaps there's a better way to do the same thing, isn't there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing your own middleware appears to be the way to go. Just put it at the end of your `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` list and implement [process_exception](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#process-exception) in it, e.g.

```
class MyMiddleware(object):
    """Handles UserFriendlyError"""
    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        if isinstance(exception, UserFriendlyError):
            return render(request, 'user_friendly_error.html', {'exception': exception})
        else:
            return None

# In your settings.py
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    # ...
    'myproject.mymiddleware.MyMiddleware',
)
```

Only seven lines of code and works as expected regardless of `DEBUG` mode and without tinkering with the 500 handler at all.