# atomic transaction is not working django rest

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using DRF, API View Class based view, post method.
Parameters are : file
Logic : Do some validation on file and save file progressively (different type of objects)
I am trying to rollback the transaction if exception happens while saving the rest of the file. I set `'ATOMIC_REQUESTS'`: `True`

```
class SaveXMlFile(APIView):
   authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
   permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
   parser_classes = [FormParser, MultiPartParser]

   def post(self, request):
      """
          Save xml file
          ---
          # inputs
          parameters:
              - name: game_log_file
                description: Game log file
                type: file
                required: true
                paramType: post
                allowMultiple: false
      """
      try:
          # import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
          game_log_file = request.data['game_log_file']
          file_store = FileStore.objects.create(uploaded_file=game_log_file)
          xml_file_processing = ProcessXmlFile(file_store)
          already_saved = xml_file_processing.was_file_saved()
          player_exists = xml_file_processing.player_exists()
          if already_saved:
              file_store.delete()
              return Response({"info": "File was saved previously, no action taken place this time."}, status=200)
          if not player_exists:
              file_store.delete()
              return Response({"info":  "No player exists in the database, ask your administrator to create some."}, status=200)
          xml_file_processing.save()
          file_store.delete()
          return Response({"success": "File has been saved."}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
      except Exception as err:
          error = "{0}".format(str(err))
          return JsonResponse({'exception': error}, status=500)
```

I am deliberately throwing exceptions when half of the file has been saved but committed transactions don't rollback even exception is raised in the process.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ATOMIC\_REQUEST and Transactions in Django 1.6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20682954/atomic-request-and-transactions-in-django-1-6)

Answer (score 6):

You should read a bit more about how transactions work with Django.
Since you are catching the exception, Django will see that everything went fine and will commit the transaction, no matter what's your response code. Taken from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/transactions/#tying-transactions-to-http-requests:

> It works like this. Before calling a view function, Django starts a
>   transaction. If the response is produced without problems, Django
>   commits the transaction. If the view produces an exception, Django
>   rolls back the transaction.

So since you're catching the exception and returning an response, Django sees no reason to perform a rollback.

Comment: So what are you suggesting, that we don't try/except our DRF atomic views?

Comment: That you don't return a response from an except clause when you expect a rollback. Instead you should raise a DRF validation exception or whatever is used those days but DRF that performs a rollback (response was made 8 years ago).

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question. What's the point of a try except, if you're just going to pass the exception in the except clause?

Comment: I believe it does respond to your question. You assume reraising the same exception which is not what I said. Most non DRF exception will end up in 500 while those raising a DRF exception should make it 400 - depends on the exception of course. Also, your question should not be a comment but a question in itself.

Comment: Ok .... so then the actual answer would be to catch the exception and re-raise a DRF exception as a 400 ... It's still not clear why that is preferable over just letting the transaction exception surface as a 500 and avoiding a try/except in the first place. The frontend would handle it appropriately, no? There's nothing in Django documentation I can find that alludes to your suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

There are two independent things here. First of all, DRF will raise a 500 response by itself, when an error occurs (so there is no need to catch exception and raise a 500 explicitely). Second of all, you may also consider applying method_decorator like so:

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.db.transaction import atomic

@method_decorator(atomic, name='dispatch')
class MyView(APIView):
  ....
```

The main rationale behind this is that using ATOMIC_REQUESTS set to True may not always be desirable due to performance penalty, but you still may want to wrap some particular views in atomic block. Of course in this case you could have used

```
with atomic():
  ... your code
```

because you have access to the method itself, but that is a bit of a digress :)

hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

For visitors from the future(Assuming time **travels**)

As a rule of thumb...

Never use try...catch when doing transactions!! Because, with transactions, you are trying to solve the problem of inconsistencies.... But, with try...catch, you are hiding inconsistencies such that a transaction fails to roll back.